# printing JPanel without displaying it to screen

Tags: java, swing, printing, jpanel

I have 2 classes. The first class contains a JPanel to be printed out. The second class prints the JPanel of the first class. How can I printout the JPanel of the first class without displaying it in to screen?

Comment: -1, Why did you repost this question? You asked the same question 11 hours ago. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162833/printing-jpanel-without-rendering-it-to-screen/6162993#6162993) Why did you delete the old question? I've gave you an answer. You never bothered to reply to the suggestion. Even if it didn't work the question should be left there so other people know what has been suggested and don't waste time making the same suggestion.

Comment: @camickr:  "..I've gave you an answer."  (muses) Probably the same answer I just gave.

Comment: @Andrew, yep, that was one of the suggestions.

Comment: it works but it doesnt do exactly what i need.....anyway thank u all

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Sreen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class.

Answer (score 0):

atlernative for your questions, because Swing APIs can do that

for JComponents which are layed by using [Absolute Positioning](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) didn't required to be visible for obtains final size,

1/ disadvantages

Absolute Layout setLaout(null) is last property how to layout JComponents

have to to create two [Top-Level Containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

- a) [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for visible JComponents
- b) [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for printing output to the Printer

forgout yout that that you'll create this JDialog on fly, because then your aplication will hold maybe 100Mb or 500Mb of RAM, create JDialog only once time and its contents put to the [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) and after printing remove JPanel from JDialog for another reusing, be ensure that you set for

```
myDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

2/ advantages

that is possible :-)