# Contents of JPanel only shown at the top of the page while printing

Tags: java, printing

I'm currently trying to add print functionality to a character generator I'm creating using Java 8. My problem is, that every single element will only be shown at the top of the page while using the shown code.

[image: screenshot]

The whole code can be found on [github](https://github.com/Antafes/Vampire-Editor/tree/issue3). The print part is located under [`src/main/java/antafes/vampireEditor/gui/BaseWindow.java`](https://github.com/Antafes/Vampire-Editor/blob/issue3/src/main/java/antafes/vampireEditor/gui/BaseWindow.java) and the page objects can be found in [`src/main/java/antafes/vampireEditor/print/`](https://github.com/Antafes/Vampire-Editor/tree/issue3/src/main/java/antafes/vampireEditor/print).

Another weird thing to me is, that the part in the lambda function is called around 10 times... Is that normal?

If you need further information, let me know.

I've managed to get it working, if I use the print preview element that is already shown for a character, at least for the currently selected page (the three lines commented out).

```java
if (!this.isAnyCharacterLoaded()) {
    return;
}

PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printerJob.setJobName(this.language.translate("printCharacter"));
printerJob.setPrintable ((graphics, pageFormat, pageNum) -> {
    if (pageNum > 0){
        return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) graphics;
    graphics2D.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
    //CharacterTabbedPane pane = (CharacterTabbedPane) charactersTabPane.getSelectedComponent();
    //PrintPreviewPanel printPreview = pane.getPrintPreview();
    //printPreview.printContent(graphics2D);
    PrintBase page;

    switch (pageNum) {
        case 0:
        default:
            page = new General(this.getActiveCharacter(), false);
            break;
    }

    Dimension dimension = new Dimension((int) pageFormat.getWidth(), (int) pageFormat.getHeight());
    page.setSize(dimension);
    page.create();
    page.paint(graphics2D);

    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
});

if (!printerJob.printDialog()) {
    return;
}

try {
    printerJob.print();
} catch (PrinterException ex) {
    // handle exception
}
```

The contents on the page should be displayed like on the print preview.

[image: screenshot print preview]

Comment: Hi, @Neithan, print preview is not visible.

Comment: I suspect the problem is here: `Dimension dimension = new Dimension((int) pageFormat.getWidth(), (int) pageFormat.getHeight());` Can be that `pageFormat` stores its values scaled to the paper size and so all values are casted towards zero. However a `Dimension` requires plain pixel values to obtain the coordinates, I will stick through the code later to debug it

Comment: @Eugene If you're referring to the code, it's commented out and thus not working. If I use this, it works and shows the content of the currently selected page. This might be the first page like shown in the second screenshot.

Comment: @Panzerkroete I've already checked that, the dimension object has it's values set correctly. I don't have the exact values at hand right now, but they're around 900 for the height and around 500 for the width.

Comment: Is you question still valid? When running the current state of your github project the preview page looks fine to me.

Comment: Hi @second, the preview page isn't the problem. The problem is, that I can't print the whole 4 pages of the character. That's what the first screenshot is showing.

Comment: @Neithan, please update the question properly.

Comment: @Eugene I've clearly stated in my first sentence, that I have a problem with printing and not with a print preview and even the title of the question only refers to printing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the component wasn't layouted correctly. @second pointed me in the right direction. As he suggested I took a look into the `ScreenImage` class. Creating an image with this class worked and thus I started implementing the print process using the `ScreenImage` class.

After a while and some thoughts about the process I figured I only need exactly one method of this class. I took the `layoutComponent()` method and used only that. With this in use the elements were layouted correctly and now show up the way I want them to.

```java
private void layoutComponent(Component component)
{
    synchronized (component.getTreeLock())
    {
        component.doLayout();

        if (component instanceof Container)
        {
            for (Component child : ((Container)component).getComponents())
            {
                this.layoutComponent(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some adjustments to the paper later everything looks like it should :)

Thanks again to @second for pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Printing multiple pages is the easy part of your question.
Use java.awt.print.Book.

It could be done like this:

```
PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printerJob.setJobName(this.language.translate("printCharacter"));

Book pBook = new Book();
pBook.append((graphics, pageFormat, pageNum) -> {

        graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
        graphics.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);

        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    },
    printerJob.defaultPage()
);

pBook.append(
    (graphics, pageFormat, pageNum) -> {

        graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        graphics.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);

        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    },
    printerJob.defaultPage()
);

printerJob.setPageable(pBook);
if (!printerJob.printDialog()) {
    return;
}

try {
    printerJob.print();
} catch (PrinterException ex) {
    // handle exception
}
```

(So each of the lamdas is still called 2 times, I am also not sure why that is the case).

---

For your printing problem:

So far I havent found a (simple) solution yet, but the root cause seems to be that your layout just doesn`t carry over when the graphic component is printed.

Basically everything is on the page, but ends up at position 0,0 (top left corner).
You might need to redo the layout using proper coordinates, or (more likely) figure out why the layout is not working.

---

Edit:
I found a Java class which can capture Images of components, 
see https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/

Seems there are some general issues with trying to use the paint method of a JComponent that has not been rendered before / is created on the fly without beeing displayed.

With the class provided in the Link it works, but the scaling still needs some work.

```
        Book pBook = new Book();
        pBook.append((graphics, pageFormat, pageNum) -> {

            Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            graphics2D.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

            PrintBase page = new General(this.getActiveCharacter(), false);

            Dimension dimension = new Dimension((int) pageFormat.getWidth(), (int) pageFormat.getHeight());
            page.setSize(dimension);
            page.create();

            BufferedImage image = ScreenImage.createImage(page);            
            graphics2D.drawImage(image,new AffineTransform(1f,0f,0f,1f,0,0), null);

            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }, printerJob.defaultPage());
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165751/printing-jpanel-without-displaying-it-to-screen

Comment: Hi @second,
thanks for taking a look at my problem. I've already seen the possibility to use the Book class and also tried it (only forgot to mention it...). I'll try the ScreenImage class and of that doesn't work I might have to rework the whole layout, as you suggested. I let you know, what did work.

Comment: If you are going to redo it, I would suggest you draw it on a Graphics component directly. This way you probably achieve a higher quality, and you can use it for both the preview and the printing. The downside is that you have to do the layout manually, but since the desired result is not a scalable UI Component (but an A4 paper) nothing speaks against it.

Comment: I'm currently trying the ScreenImage class. Creating the image file itself is working, but I can't get it to print that image...

Comment: Got it working, but the quality is pretty bad... I'll see if I can do something about that. If not, I have to rework the whole layout of the print preview...

Comment: Actually if your write the BufferedImage directly to a file it looks okay (it probably won`t be bettter than this anyway), so the major issue for you is that it does not fit on the A4 paper (and so the applied scaling makes it look worse than it is). Based on this there is probably no need to redo the layout entirely, just fix the sizes so that it fits.

Comment: Found another solution for that based on what ScreenImage does. Got it so far as to correctly place the elements. Now I only need to make some adjustments to the positioning on the A4 paper ^^ I'll let you and everyone else know of my solution after it's complete and you can count on the award being yours :)