# How to customize an A4 page in java?

Tags: java, printing

I'm on an internship where my objective is to create a CRM program(Customer Relationship Management) and I need some help. 
I'm stuck on the printing of quotations and bills.

Here is my question:
 Is there any module which helps users to create a customized A4 default Page? (to automatically replace the information)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `java.awt.print.PrinterJob` & `java.awt.print.Book`. In this case you would get a `graphics` object on which you could draw your content. There are probably plenty of other ways around to print things.

Comment: And is it possible to see the page? For example with windows builder you place the component on the JFrame where you want and it generates the code automatically. Is it possible to do the same for templates?

Comment: I have answerd this question  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647884/contents-of-jpanel-only-shown-at-the-top-of-the-page-while-printing/56763733#56763733) before, In the end he copied stuff from a JPanel to the graphics object. -- Seems the github project is no longer around.

Comment: I'll try that thanks.